# UITextView text color changing after editing

Tags: swift, uitextfield, tvos, uitextfielddelegate

So I have an issue where I've made a subclass of `UITextView` to change the various colors before and after focusing. I've found thought that after actually entering in text it pretty much disregards the text color I specified.

My code looks like below. Note, I have a dictionary called `colors` that maps state ("focused" or "unfocused") to another dictionary containing the colors for the field's background and text

```
func setColors(state:String) {
        self.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: (self.attributedPlaceholder?.string)!, attributes:  [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: self.colors[state]!["text"]!])
        self.backgroundColor = self.colors[state]!["background"]
        self.layer.borderColor = self.colors[state]!["background"]!.CGColor
        self.textColor = self.colors[state]!["text"]
        self.tintColor = self.colors[state]!["text"]
    }

override func didUpdateFocusInContext(context: UIFocusUpdateContext, withAnimationCoordinator coordinator: UIFocusAnimationCoordinator) {
        super.didUpdateFocusInContext(context, withAnimationCoordinator: coordinator)

        if context.nextFocusedView == self {
            coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
                self.setColors("focused")
            }, completion: nil)
        }
        else {
            coordinator.addCoordinatedAnimations({ () -> Void in
                self.setColors("unfocused")
            }, completion: nil)
        }
    }
```

So before I type in anything it looks fine. Switching between fields on the view the colors all look right. However when I select a field and enter in text afterwards the only thing that looks right is the background color, which changes as appropriate when focused/unfocused. Is there another text color attribute that is set after text is entered in?